# Why Am I Getting An Expected an Assignment or Function Call and Instead Saw an Expression?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import Login from '../Login/Login';

const Authenticate = App => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        loggedIn: false
      };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      localStorage.getItem('username') ?
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: true
        }) :
        null;
    }

    render() {
      return this.state.loggedIn === false ? < Login / > : < App / > ;
    }
  };
};

export default Authenticate;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

/src/components/Authentication/Authenticate.js
  Line 13:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Can you actually write JSX like that? I would think it would need to be `<Login />` and `<App />`. Also, why the conditional operator abuse? Use an `if` in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: For some reason, I think the "tidy" added some weird spacing... I generally don't space it like that.

Comment: Oh, this is an eslint error, not a syntax error. Using an `if` statement will fix it.

Comment: I refactored it to an if statement, and still got the same error.. very strange..

Comment: Please show what you changed it to.

Comment: I added my answer. Thank you for your help Ry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ternary operators can’t be used like you did instead do it like below

```
  componentDidMount() {
      if(localStorage.getItem('username')){
           this.setState({
              loggedIn: true
           }) 
      }
  }
```

Render part can be corrected as follows. This is not mandatory though but good to follow like this like assigning all the state or props to const like below instead of calling this.state several times in render and Boolean equality check should not be like === false just using ! Is best practice

```
 render() {
    const { loggedIn } = this.state;
     return (
          <div>
              {!loggedIn ? < Login / > : < App / > }
           </div>
      )
 }
```

Or in React v16 call it like

```
   render() {
    const { loggedIn } = this.state;
     return (
          <React.Fragment>
              {!loggedIn ? < Login / > : < App / > }
           </React.Fragment>
      )
 }
```

Comment: They can be used like that; an ESLint rule just complains. Also, `render()` didn’t need to be changed.

Comment: I suggested better way of doing render part

Answer (score 2):

You can address this via changing your code in the `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: localStorage.getItem('username') ? true : false
    })
}
```

or if you do not want to set the state:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('username'))
       this.setState({
         loggedIn: true
       })
}
```

The main reason for this error is ESLint and more specifically the `Ternary` rules [specified here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions#allowternary).

**This is not allowed** by the `Disallow Unused Expressions` rule and its `allowTernary` option:

> a ? b : 0
>
> a ? b : c()

This however **is allowed**:

> a ? b() : c()
>
> a ? (b = c) : d()

Here is a [Repl with it rendering without the error](https://repl.it/@akrion/ParallelHideousDownloads)

Comment: That worked, thank you! Any reason why the other way didn't work? Just for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount() {
        if(localStorage.getItem('username')){
    this.setState({loggedIn:true})
  }
    }
```

This solved it perfectly, thank you for all the help.